# What exactly makes negative energy negative?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, conventions

Antimatter is the opposite of matter since it has opposite electric charge (e.g. proton -> positive whilst anti-proton -> negative).

So what exactly makes negative energy negative? What property does it have to make it the opposite of 'positive' or 'zero' energy?

Comment: What exactly makes a negative bank account balance negative?  Your question seems to imply that energy is an absolute, but often "energy" describes some _change_ in the energy of a system.

Comment: If energy describes the change in the energy of a system, then what quantifies the energy of a system? I might be misunderstanding something here.

Comment: I am not a physicist, and I don't know where you got the idea of "negative energy." Maybe you know something I don't. On the other hand, I remember problems from high-school physics where there was a variable called "energy" with Joules as the unit, but the value was relative to some arbitrary reference point.  E.g., the gravitational potential energy of some weight, and the reference point is where the weight is sitting on the ground. Let the weight fall into a hole, below ground level, and the "potential energy" variable must go negative.

Comment: Or, going back to the bank account analogy: There is no such thing as negative money, and yet your bank account balance, which is measured in some currency unit ("dollars", "euros", "rupees", etc.), can and will go negative if the bank allows you to overdraw your account.

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/Hawking-radiation I got the idea of negative energy when I was trying to find out what Hawking Radiation was about. But thank you for simplifying the idea with the analogy.

Comment: You somehow jump to the conclusion that negative energy is involved, but this is not the case. Antimatter corresponds to positive energy.

Comment: @my2cts While your comment is correct for real particles, the OP is asking about virtual (off-shell) antiparticles with a negative energy entering a black hole to reduce its total energy in the Hawking radiation mechanism.

Comment: @safesphere where do you read y hat in this post? There's no mention if a black hole, virtual particles, Hawking radiation at all. Are you sure you comment isn't an unintentional  cross post?

Comment: @my2cts He clarifies it in the comments.

Comment: @safesphere You are reading too.much into this, I'm sure.

Comment: @my2cts He says, "*I got the idea of negative energy when I was trying to find out what Hawking Radiation was about.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that you're (infinitely) far away from Earth - define this point as your potential energy $E_p = 0$ as Earth does not affect you. Now imagine you are on the surface of Earth and want to get to that point - how do you do that? You need to add energy to yourself/your spaceship to counteract Earth's gravity and escape - so you add this energy to the potential energy you experience on the surface to get to the desired point. This means that while on Earth, your potential energy is negative.